# How to inject data-inject-svg in ERB (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg, erb

I'm using a library called *svg-injector* in order to inject SVGs in HTML.

**HTML syntax:**

```
<img class="navbar" data-inject-svg src="icons/interface/icon-menu.svg">
```

Any ideas on how to use this `data-inject-svg` in ERB templating?

```
<%= image_tag "icons/interface/icon-menu.svg", class: "navbar", data-inject-svg %>
```

**This Won't work.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<%= image_tag "icons/interface/icon-menu.svg", class: "navbar", data: { inject: { svg: "icons/interface/icon-menu.svg" } } %>
```

or

```
<%= image_tag "icons/interface/icon-menu.svg", class: "navbar", "data-inject-svg" => "icons/interface/icon-menu.svg" %>
```